# Binary vectors as y_score argument of roc_curve

Tags: scikit-learn, roc

The sklearn roc_curve [docstring](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_curve.html#sklearn.metrics.roc_curve) states:

"y_score : array, shape = [n_samples]
Target scores, can either be probability estimates of the positive class, confidence values, or binary decisions."

In what situation it would make sense to set y_score to a binary vector ("binary decisions")? Wouldn't that result in a ROC curve with one point on it which kind of defies the point?

Comment: Yes. You shouldn't do that. Maybe open a PR changing the docstring and saying that that is not very advisable.

Comment: Done: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/2874 :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using a classifier that does not output probability scores (e.g. `svm.SVC` without an explicit `probability=True`), there isn't a way to compute a ROC curve. As an API designer, you have two choices: raise an exception and provide the user no useful information, or plot a degenerate curve with one data point. I would argue the latter is more useful.

Comment: We actually had a student who generated those degenerate ROC curves, calculated AUC and thought everything is all right. I would lean towards raising an exception.