# scikit-learn roc_auc_score() returns accuracy values

Tags: python, scikit-learn, scikits

I am trying to compute area under the ROC curve using `sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score` using the following method:

```
roc_auc = sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score(actual, predicted)
```

where `actual` is a binary vector with ground truth classification labels and `predicted` is a binary vector with classification labels that my classifier has predicted.

However, the value of `roc_auc` that I am getting is EXACTLY similar to accuracy values (proportion of samples whose labels are correctly predicted). This is not a one-off thing. I try my classifier on various values of the parameters and every time I get the same result.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is because you are passing in the decisions of you classifier instead of the scores it calculated. There was a [question on this on SO recently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21829131/binary-vectors-as-y-score-argument-of-roc-curve) and a related pull request to `scikit-learn`.

The point of a ROC curve (and the area under it) is that you study the precision-recall tradeoff as the classification threshold is varied. By default in a binary classification task, if your classifier's score is  `> 0.5`, then `class1` is predicted, otherwise `class0` is predicted. As you change that threshold, you get a curve like [this](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/plot_roc.html). The higher up the curve is (more area under it), the better that classifier. However, to get this curve you need access to the scores of a classifier, not its decisions. Otherwise whatever the decision threshold is, the decision stay the same, and AUC degenerates to accuracy.

Which classifier are you using?

Comment: I am not using any built-in classifier. It is rather a heuristic that is applicable to my particular experiment and it does not give any confidence values, only the classification label. Do you have any suggestion here?

Comment: Also, the problem only seems to occur when I am passing balanced data (same number of +ve and -ve examples) to `roc_auc_score()`. If I pass unbalanced data (but the binary vectors), the results of accuracy and AUC are different.

Comment: You can meaningfully calculate AUC if you don't have confidence values, AFAIK. There are other performance metrics though.